# ServiceStack OrmLiteAuthRepository.UpdateUserAuth with null password

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I'm not sure if this is an issue, or just a matter of me not knowing how the OrmLiteAuthRepository should work.  I'm trying to make an admin screen that allows admins to update users information.  I'm using the OrmLiteAuthRepository.UpdateUserAuth method and passing in a null password to update everything but the password.  However, validation is ran as if I'm creating a new user and ValidateNewUser requires me to have a password that is not null even though further in the method there are checks to avoid updating the password if a null password is used.  I'm I missing something?

Here is a link to the method call

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/Auth/OrmLiteAuthRepository.cs#L105

Comment: If you have your own validation in place and make sure that your username or email isn't updated to one that is already taken, @Gavin Faux is right, you can just use SaveUserAuth.  However, to keep the api clean, I cloned the project and will be turning in to SS to be reviewed.

Answer (score 3):

Use `SaveUserAuth`, I believe UpdateUserAuth is for updating password, though could be wrong.

```
UserAuth user = this.AuthRepository.GetUserAuth("bob")
 if (user.Meta == null)
 {
     user.Meta = new Dictionary<string, string>();
 }
 user.Meta.Add("message", "hi bob");
 this.AuthRepository.SaveUserAuth(user);
```

Comment: SaveUserAuth does not run through all the validation that UpdateUserAuth runs.  SaveUserAuth would let you update an account with an existing Username or Email.  UpdateUserAuth checks for things like that and throws an exception.

Comment: Had not thought of that particular use case, so would need a pull request to implement I guess. Or don't allow username to be changed in your admin UI.